Can you set a global filter for a table in Entity Framework Core from outside the context?
I have a table which has the field Deleted (Boolean, True if deleted, False if not).
I add the filter to the whole table using this:
modelBuilder.Entity<Books>().HasQueryFilter(e => !e.Deleted);

I am afraid that in subsequent rebuilds of the context I might forget to add the line above to the OnModelCreating method.
Is there a way to ensure that this filter will exist even after rebuilding the whole context? Like is there a way to add the filter from outside the context so that it is active for the whole context?

What you ask is a soft delete and while it's not a good idea, and certainly NOT a business requirement, there are a lot of duplicate questions. EF like all ORMs deals with application entities, not tables. It doesn't have to map to just tables either. You can create a view that only includes non-deleted row and map to it. In most databases the view will be editable as long as the primary key fields are included

As for why it's a bad idea, it's because real businesses never mark anything as "deleted". They perform balancing or compensating transactions, or change the status of an entity. When you cancel a ticket reservation airlines perform a cancellation or refund transaction, they don't mark your reservation as "deleted". Soft deletes are the quick & dirty way developers try to handle this requirement without actually handling it. This fails the very first time you eg "delete" a customer and are left with orders pointing to that "deleted" customer. Or a shipment pointing to a soft-deleted order

Why do you want soft deletes? It's quite possible EF or the database can handle the real requirement. For auditing, or point-in-time queries, SQL Server's temporal tables or the equivalent in other databases, can solve the problem at the database level while maintaining referential integrity. Auditing requirements can be covered with SaveChanges interceptors.

I agree with your points, but the issue comes down to the client "accidentally" deleting records he requires and blames developers for carelessness, although logs show us who did it. Using the soft delete we have a quick and easy way to remove the records from his listings and referential connections and in case the client wants we can restore it with minimal effort. I wanted to escape creating a view for that table, because of the required additional maintenance to match the table and the view column definitions.

So the real requirement is auditing. That's what temporal tables and auditing interceptors or triggers solve, not soft deletes. If the client accidentally runs DELETE, which they can, the data is gone without either temporal tables or DELETE triggers that update a history table

required additional maintenance you mean SELECT * ? Or expanding * to actual columns with Ctrl+Shift+Q in SSMS or the equivalent in any IDE? The real maintenance issue is that soft deletes break integrity. When the customer soft-deletes an order and still finds it referenced in a shipment, they'll have every right to complain

You should probably check this similar question: Using Global Query Filters for all entities. You should keep in mind that the more quick fixes you add instead of handling the actual requirements, the harder it will be to do so when the quick fixes start failing. If you intend to to use soft delete on "all" types, you can use marker interfaces or attributes to mark the types that can't use soft delete

You probably still need history tables, if you want to find out how multiple tables looked at a specific point in time. Soft deletes will only recover individual entities, not their related entities. And certainly not the history of changes to them
